# Can I Access 2b2t on a Nintendo Switch?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I play Minecraft on the Nintendo Switch, and I want to know: is there any way for me to get onto the [2b2t](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2b2t) server on it?

Comment: The currently-accepted answer is both unhelpful and *materially* incorrect w/r/t the question **as stated**. Would you consider looking through the others that have been posted since, to see if another is more fitting of being Accepted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, 2b2t is only compatible with an older version of the Java Edition client (currently at version 1.12.2 at the time of this answer). You can only join the 2b2t with the specific version of Minecraft that the server is running.

Comment: Hey, I'm just wondering the reason for the rollback? In my opinion the phrasing of this answer seems to be much more confusing then it needs to be, making it seem like a "legacy version" is the reason you can't.

Comment: Well beyond the fact that your edit completely re-wrote the answer with poor grammer and missing words, "legacy version" is the accurate term. 2b2t does not run modern Minecraft. It runs version 1.12.2 which was release in 2017. You can only play it with an older version of the Minecraft Java Edition client. If the server was running on Realms then you could get to it with other clients than just the Java Edition, so there is a distinction.

Comment: as i said, "legacy version" is **not** the reason you cant use it. If it ran 1.16 it doesnt matter u still cant play it on bedrock. Also grammar is a fix for editing, not rollbacks. (i guess ignoring 3rd party software which if thats the case this should be rewritten as that is not at all apparent

Comment: If it ran on Realms you play it from Bedrock.

Comment: but thats not apparent. You should then *explain* it. Your comment is almost as helpful as your answer, it would be best to add that in

Comment: I gotta say I've never seen anyone use "F'x" before and it looks like a math problem xD

Answer (score 4):

It's theoretically possible - a tool called Geyser lets you connect to Java Edition servers on Bedrock, even on console, according to this video:

It may be possible to connect to 1.12 servers (using VIAaaS), but I don't have a console to test it on, and you do need a Java Edition account (and a PC or Mac) if all of this is possible, so it's more something to do as an experiment, not something to do if you don't want to buy Java Edition.

If anyone does want to do this, here are some useful links:

https://github.com/GeyserMC/Geyser/wiki/Setup#console-setup

https://github.com/GeyserMC/Geyser/issues/607

https://github.com/ViaVersion/VIAaaS (thanks jamestheawesomedude)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know if there **is any way** for me to get onto the 2b2t server on it?

Yes, **there is a way.**

[image: screenshot of a Minecraft: Bedrock Edition player; their coordinates are 0, 240, 0 in The End; there are no blocks in sight; a single chat message shows "Position in queue: 705"]

For this method, you'll need **three** third-party tools:

- [Geyser](https://geysermc.org/) (to allow a Bedrock Edition client to connect to a Java Edition server)
- [ViaVersion Standalone](https://github.com/ViaVersion/VIAaaS) (to allow a 1.16 client to connect to a 1.12 server (because, despite keeping the server on 1.12, 2B2T's admin has decided *not* to install [ViaVersion](https://github.com/ViaVersion/ViaVersion).))
- [BedrockConnect](https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/dchatu/bedrockconnect_an_easy_way_for_minecraft_bedrock/) (to allow a console port to connect to a custom server)

## Setup

### Geyser (Standalone)

Get a cheap VPS (or just an unused computer at your house); ensure it's got Java on it (preferably version 11 or newer), and run the Geyser **Standalone** file (`Geyser.jar`), which can be downloaded from [their CI server](https://ci.opencollab.dev//job/GeyserMC/job/Geyser/job/master/).

Edit its `config.yml` and set

- `remote`→`address` to `2b2t.org._v1_12_2.viaaas.localhost`
- `server-name` to `2b2t.org`
- `motd1` to `2B2T Proxy` (and remove `motd2`)
- `show-cooldown` to `false` (it's currently disruptive on consoles)

then **restart** Geyser to reload the changes.

(Also, don't forget to open `19132/udp` in whatever firewall the machine may have.)

Remember this server's IP — you'll need it later!

### ViaVersion (Standalone)

On a computer or VPS (preferably **the same one** you're using for Geyser), also with Java 11, download ViaVersion Standalone from [their CI server](https://github.com/ViaVersion/VIAaaS/actions): go to the latest successful run, scroll down to download the Artifact, *(unfortunately, this requires a GitHub account — fortunately, these [are free](https://github.com/join);)* and extract+run `VIAaaS-0.2.#-SNAPSHOT+#######-all.jar` from it.

(Also, don't forget to open `25543/tcp` in whatever firewall the machine may have.)

In your web browser, go to `https://viaversion-server:25543/` (except instead of `viaversion-server`, actually put the IP or hostname of the ViaVersion Standalone server). You will have to accept and connect to a self-signed certificate.

After ensuring that “CORS Proxy status” is “OK” (if it's not, go to “Settings” and paste `https://crp123-cors.herokuapp.com/` — or, if you're paranoid, you could look into [running your own](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere) — then go back to Home); click on `Listen to premium login`, and use a Java Edition Minecraft client to follow through with the authentication. Then, click `Listen to _your_username_` and ensure it shows it's listening for your UUID.

(Leave this browser window open.)

### BedrockConnect

Once your "Geyser Server" and ViaVersion Standalone proxy are running (remember to leave that browser open!), you will need to configure your device* with BedrockConnect to allow it to connect to 3rd-party servers.

(*The Nintendo Switch, Xbox One, and PlayStation 4 require this; Android, iOS, Windows 10, and Fire/Fire TV editions do not; if you are on one of the latter platforms, **skip this step.**)

To do this, you should change its network configuration; set its DNS to manual: the primary DNS to `104.238.130.180`, and the secondary to `1.1.1.1` (or your favorite DNS server).

If you have problems, you [might](https://github.com/Pugmatt/BedrockConnect/issues/154) want to try one of their [other servers](https://github.com/Pugmatt/BedrockConnect#publicly-available-bedrockconnect-instances), such as `173.82.100.84`; or even [host your own](https://github.com/Pugmatt/BedrockConnect#hosting-your-own-serverlist-server).

Once Geyser is running, and your Switch (or PS4 or XBO) is configured to use BedrockConnect, you're all ready to go!

## Connecting

Open Minecraft, go to Multiplayer, join any server that has `Join to open server list` as its MOTD.

Then, log in with your Java account credentials and enter **the IP of the GeyserMC server** you prepared earlier *(NOT `2b2t.org`!)* as the Server Address.

Quickly look back at the browser on which you had pulled up ViaVersion, and authorize the connection ("impersonation") after confirming the IP's correct.

– *et voilà~!*

Answer (score 1):

No,2b2t is on the Java edition of Minecraft while switch uses bedrock edition.

Answer (score 1):

No, since 2b2t is on java edition and NOT hosted with geyser or a similar program bedrock players can't connect. Even if it was hosted with bedrock compatibility, you still wouldn't be able to play on it since you can't add custom servers on switch.

Comment: Geyser can be run by an end user. And you can connect the switch to a fake network and it will think it's lan server

Comment: @RayWu There's still the issue of version-compatibility… the admin has declined to install ViaVersion, but the server's still on 1.12

Comment: From a suggested edit: "You can add custom servers just not 2b2t or non bedrock supported servers"